# Redirect domain.com/path to another Apache Server

Tags: apache, proxypass

I have 3 Apache VM's running currently:

```
A) ProxyPass (Hosts Nothing)
B) Main Website
C) ZoneMinder Website
```

If you access example.com you get to the website, and can navigate around, but...

If I manually type http://example.com/zm trying to access zoneminder

It redirects http://example.com/zm in my remote browser to http://192.168.1.255:443/foo*

**I can't seem to get my redirect working correctly, can anybody see what I am doing wrong?**

**Configs:**

**A) ProxyPass Server:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          www.example.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.255:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.255:80/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**B) Main Website**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working!

The setup:

Server A) Apache server that only serves proxypass and doesn't host anything

Server B) Apache server that hosts main domain.com

Server C) Apache server that hosts ZoneMinder @ domain.com/zm

Server A Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
Redirect / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.domain.com
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /location of .crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /location of .key
SSLCACertificateFile /location of .crt
ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass /zm https://192.168.1.43:443/zm
ProxyPassReverse /zm https://192.168.1.43:443/zm


ProxyPass / https://192.168.1.42:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.42:443/

<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Notes: It is important to have the /zm come before the "/" catch all. I also noticed it FAILED if i used /zm/.

Server B Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /location of .crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /location of .key
SSLCACertificateFile /location of .crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: it is not necessary to have *:80 redirects or Server Alias as only correctly formatted requests are sent to this server via ProxyPass filtering beforehand.

Server C Config: (domain.com/zm)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /location of .crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /location of .key
SSLCACertificateFile /location of .crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Yes it is the same. It works so I am happy!

Note: All 3 servers have my SSL certs installed, but I did not touch default-ssl.conf.